# control width of separation lines in d3 sunburst diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm using a modified version of [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423) in an app showing a tree-like structure using a sunburst diagram, and I was wondering if there's anyway to control the width of the thin white lines separating each wedge.

[image: d3 sunburst diagram]

There's nothing explicitly set in the code regarding this lines, and a quick look of the documentation of the d3 library regarding this layout ([here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout)) does not mention anything about them, or at least I did not find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its applying the css property style `stroke:rgb(255, 255, 255);`
The css property to adjust the thickness of the stroke is `stroke-width`

I will warn you though, the larger your stroke width, the "smaller" your colored block will appear to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll be trying that. However, what I intend to is to make them thinner, if that's possible at all. I doubt it, but our designer asked, and I promised to check if it's possible.

Comment: FYI, I was able to make them thinner, to my surprise. It turns out that `stroke-width: .5px` works as expected.